# defining type annotation for functions

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to wrap my head around the concept of type annotation of typescript for functions and i came across 3 versions of type annotation for an arrow function definition which i would like to understand the difference.

```
const addTwoVariable: (a: number, b: number) => number = (a, b) => {
    return a + b;
}

const anotherAddTwoVariable = (a: number, b: number): number => {
    return a + b;
}

const ultimateAddTwoVariable: (a: number, b: number) => number = (a: number, b: number): number => {
  return a + b;
}
```

Comment: Where did you find these? I would consider `anotherAddTwoVariable` to be a "normal" type annotation, and I have no idea what the other two are trying to accomplish (As in, they seem overly verbose for no added benefit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typing a function is useful only in interface in my opinion, because a function type is inferred (if everything is well typed), so `anotherAddTwoVariable` is the best approach (because typing the parameters and the return type is enough for the function to be of type `(a: number, b: number) => number`

Here are the differences :

`addTwoVariable` is first typed with `(a: number, b: number) => number`, then the implementation doesn't need any types informations thanks to the typing. So `a` and `b` are automatically typed as number, and so is the returned type (that would have been inferred anyway)

`anotherAddTwoVariable` is the normal way to implement a function, and doesn't need a general typing because each parameters are typed (and so is the return type, but there again `a` and `b` being numbers, the return type would have been inferred anyway)

`ultimateAddTwoVariable` is a combination of the two above and is really not necessary. It is like doing `let myVar: string = 'hello'`, it is useless because TypeScript will automatically infer those types

However like i said, typing a function in an interface is useful

```
interface IMyInterface {
  method(a: number, b:number): number
}

const object: IMyInterface = {
  method: (a, b) => a + b // Everything is already typed
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: thanks for the thorough answer. so if i understood correctly the difference between addTwoVariable and anotherAddTwoVariable, is that in the first case we declare types upon definition of the function whereas in later case we declare types upon implementing the function?

Comment: Exactly, and in general it is not a good practice to type a function while implementing it because it adds unecessary complexity while reading it.